# code works for java graphics, but not graphics2d

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

inside a paintcomponent. it takes g as parameter, and g can be graphics or graphics2d. the class extends jpanel. then:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
this.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
```

if g is graphics it works, but if it's graphics2d it doesn't. it compiles with both, but graphics2d doesn't change the background color. how come?

Answer (score 4):

[`JPanel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) (which is a subclass of [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)) only has a [`paintComponent(Graphics)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method. It does not have a method with the signature `paintComponent(Graphics2D)`.

Overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method can be accomplished by the following:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    // Do things.
}
```

However, defining a method with the signature with `paintComponent(Graphics2D)` like the following is legal, but *it won't ever be called*, as it is not overriding any method that is defined in `JComponent`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
{
    // Do things.
    // However, this method will never be called, as it is not overriding any
    // method of JComponent, but is a method of the class this is defined in.
}
```

The [Java API specifications for the `JComponent` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) (which is the superclass of `JPanel`) has a method summary which lists all the methods that are part of the class.

More information about painting in Swing;

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)